# Error in launching AVD on Windows 7 Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, hyper-v, haxm

I am trying to start emulator on newly installed Android Studio but I am getting following error:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I tried to install HAXM from extras but I keep on getting following error:

VT not supported

then I tried this about which I read in another forum:
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

but its also failing with below error:
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Image Version: 6.1.7601.18489

Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

Although I checked from BIOS setup that my processor supports VT and its enabled in BIOS.

My system configurations is:
Intel i5 2410,
Windows 4 64-bit,
JDK7,
Android SDK 24.0.1,
Android Studio 1.0.1,

Please help to solve this issue if anyone has been able to solve it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was caused by VirtualBox. After uninstalling VB everything worked fine but when I was doing some research about this problem it seemed like other things can generate this error. If you have virtualBox try to uninstall it, if you don't well... sorry, can't help.

Comment: actually I uninstalled Avast and its working now. after installing HAXM I re-installed Avast. Everything is Fine. Avast was culprit blocking it.